# Is there a way to convert huge decimal numbers(x10^8) to binary?

Tags: binary

I have a code to convert my decimal number to a binary number but since the number is huge 1,4e8, it either always gives me a round number or it uses too much memory and crashes here is my code

```
double n = 1466333969;
    double e = 10487;
    double facteurs = 0;
    long d = 0;

    facteurs = factorisation(n);
    d = calculerD(facteurs, e);

    long  dTemp = d / 2;
    int dBin[70] = {};
    int i = 0;

    cout << dTemp << endl;

    do
    {
        if (dTemp == floor(d / 2))
        {
            //cout << D << " " << dTemp << endl;
            dBin[i] = 0;
        }
        else dBin[i] = 1;

        d = floor(d / 2);
        dTemp = d / 2;
        //cout << D << " " << dBin[i] << endl;
        i++;

    } while (d != 0);
```

I checked and the calculerD function works fine and return the right d but afterwards, it just seems to stay in longs.

Comment: Check the memory assumptions of space requires for *working* code: `log2(10^8)` (This is clearly 'not a memory problem' for computers..)

Comment: What does "I have a code to convert my decimal number to a binary number" mean? All numbers are binary in the computer. Do you have a string somewhere? Something in [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)?

Comment: @user1118321 OP is storing `0` or `1` in `int[] dBin` (aka sequence of binary representing the decimal number, regardless of storage or representation).

Comment: I need to convert 146'667'683 to binary, I also need to use the method where you divide your number by 2 and use the rest to find the binary. Sorry if it's not clear btw im trying my best but I am french and have difficulty explaining sometimes.

Comment: OK, I see. What does "it just seems to stay in longs" mean?

Comment: So whenever I cout the dTemp, which is a long double, its always an integer number and I never have decimals.

Comment: I also change dTemp to a long double but it doesn't seemed to have changed anything I still lose precision